# Flutter || Padding for floatingActionButton in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, padding

In my flutter project I used a floatingActionButton and I want to add a padding but I don't know how to make the tree with my code. Any help is highly appreciated.

This is my code :

```
 floatingActionButton: Visibility(
              visible: buttonshow,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  scrollToTop();
                },
                shape: const StadiumBorder(
                    side: BorderSide(
                        color: Color(0xff135888), width: 2.5)),
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                elevation: 0.0,
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.keyboard_arrow_up, color: Color(0xff135888),
                  size: 28.0,),
                mini: true,

              ),
            ),
```

Comment: How about wrapping `Visibility` with `Padding` widget.

Comment: Yeah I don't know how can I wrap it. Please can you upload the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your Visibility with an Expanded Widget.

Updated code:

```
floatingActionButton: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Visibility(
    visible: buttonshow,
    child: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        scrollToTop();
      },
      shape: const StadiumBorder(
          side: BorderSide(color: Color(0xff135888), width: 2.5)),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0.0,
      child: const Icon(
        Icons.keyboard_arrow_up,
        color: Color(0xff135888),
        size: 28.0,
      ),
      mini: true,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: I want my VIsibility widget to stay too

Comment: I have just added sample code... you can wrap Padding with Visibility

Comment: @SOUDEYUIH updated code check it once